NonUniqueObjectException Coming from JBPM 4.4
I am using grails APP, and jbpm4.4 jar.
One of the object BlobVariable in jar throwing NonUniqueObjectException.
stack trace:
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 

[org.jbpm.pvm.internal.lob.Lob#12192477]
at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.hibernate.DbSessionImpl.delete(DbSessionImpl.java:101)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.type.variable.BlobVariable.setObject(BlobVariable.java:51)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.type.Variable.setValue(Variable.java:95)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.type.variable.BlobVariable.setValue(BlobVariable.java:66)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.DeserializedObject.flush(DeserializedObject.java:63)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.AbstractTransaction.flushDeserializedObjects(AbstractTransaction.java:54)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.SpringCommandCallback.doInTransaction(SpringCommandCallback.java:47)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.executeInNewEnvironment(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.RetryInterceptor.execute(RetryInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.ExecutionServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:71)
    at com.saviynt.ecm.services.WorkflowService.workflowaccessreqStart(WorkflowService.groovy:1084)
    at com.saviynt.ws.JbpmapiService.workflowaccessreqStartMS(JbpmapiService.groovy:64)
    at com.saviynt.ecm.ws.JbpmapiController$_closure4.doCall(JbpmapiController.groovy:61)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at com.saviynt.webservice.SaviyntRestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SaviyntRestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:158)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
    at com.mrhaki.grails.plugin.xframeoptions.web.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilterInternal(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:69)
    at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

